# How to find a central hub of weighted vertices

Tags: python, tree

So I'm working on a program that takes a set of vertices and makes a Kruskal Spanning tree out of them. I got that down but now I need to take the vertices and find a center hub, by that i need to find what vertices has the shortest total distance between all the other vertices. I was thinking to make a BFS tree but I'm not sure how I would implement the points and there distance to do it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
 
# Class to represent a graph
 
 
class Graph:
 
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.V = vertices  # No. of vertices
        self.graph = []  # default dictionary
        # to store graph
 
    # function to add an edge to graph
    def addEdge(self, u, v, w):
        self.graph.append([u, v, w])
 
    # A utility function to find set of an element i
    # (uses path compression technique)
    def find(self, parent, i):
        if parent[i] == i:
            return i
        return self.find(parent, parent[i])
 
    # A function that does union of two sets of x and y
    # (uses union by rank)
    def union(self, parent, rank, x, y):
        xroot = self.find(parent, x)
        yroot = self.find(parent, y)
 
        # Attach smaller rank tree under root of
        # high rank tree (Union by Rank)
        if rank[xroot] < rank[yroot]:
            parent[xroot] = yroot
        elif rank[xroot] > rank[yroot]:
            parent[yroot] = xroot
 
        # If ranks are same, then make one as root
        # and increment its rank by one
        else:
            parent[yroot] = xroot
            rank[xroot] += 1
 
    # The main function to construct MST using Kruskal's
        # algorithm
    def KruskalMST(self):
 
        result = []  # This will store the resultant MST
         
        # An index variable, used for sorted edges
        i = 0
         
        # An index variable, used for result[]
        e = 0
 
        # Step 1:  Sort all the edges in
        # non-decreasing order of their
        # weight.  If we are not allowed to change the
        # given graph, we can create a copy of graph
        self.graph = sorted(self.graph,
                            key=lambda item: item[2])
 
        parent = []
        rank = []
 
        # Create V subsets with single elements
        for node in range(self.V):
            parent.append(node)
            rank.append(0)
 
        # Number of edges to be taken is equal to V-1
        while e < self.V - 1:
 
            # Step 2: Pick the smallest edge and increment
            # the index for next iteration
            u, v, w = self.graph[i]
            i = i + 1
            x = self.find(parent, u)
            y = self.find(parent, v)
 
            # If including this edge does't
            #  cause cycle, include it in result
            #  and increment the indexof result
            # for next edge
            if x != y:
                e = e + 1
                result.append([u, v, w])
                self.union(parent, rank, x, y)
            # Else discard the edge
 
        minimumCost = 0
        print ("Edges in the constructed MST")
        for u, v, weight in result:
            minimumCost += weight
            print("%d -- %d == %d" % (u, v, weight))
        print("Minimum Spanning Tree" , minimumCost)
 
# Driver code
g = Graph(4)
# so point 0 goes to 1 with a distance of 10
g.addEdge(0, 1, 10)
g.addEdge(0, 2, 6)
g.addEdge(0, 3, 5)
g.addEdge(1, 3, 15)
g.addEdge(2, 3, 4)
 
# Function call
g.KruskalMST()
```

Comment: Your subject mentions "weighted vertices", but your code has weighted edges, not weighted vertices. I suppose the title is wrong in that respect?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a tree  (the minimal spanning tree derived from the initial graph), and need to find the node  in  such that the maximum distance it has to any other node in  is minimised.

This can be done in two steps, both linear in time in terms of the number of nodes in :

1. Determine the longest path in . This can be done with two traversals (either depth or breadth first):

   Pick a node  and find the node  that is furthest from it in . Then perform a second traversal starting in  to find the node  that is furthest from it in . The path (, ) represents a longest path in . See also [Linear algorithm for longest path in tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187404/linear-time-algorithm-for-longest-path-in-tree)
2. The problem is now reduced to finding the "middle" node  on the path (, ). Perform a simplified breadth-first search on the path starting in  and : so you have references   that traverse towards each other along , always keeping dist(, ) and dist(, ) in  at a minimum. The node  where  and  will meet is the middle node . The node that is furthest from node  in  is either  or .

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?